# Regex to Remove File Extension

Tags: plugins, regex

I am using the Redirection plugin and I would like to use it to redirect my old static html pages to the new Wordpress pages. So basically anything that looks like http://www.example.com/page.html becomes http://www.example.com/page/

The only catch is that I want to exclude a folder so anything that is http://www.example.com/specialfolder/page.html shall remain untouched.

Comment: Do you want to exclude one folder? Or all folders? If it's all folders, this should work:      

    RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)\.html$ http://www.example.com/$1/

Comment: no I want to exclude 1 folder (and its sub folders). Thanks for your help (and plugins!)

Answer (score 2):

Let's see, this should do the trick then:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/specialfolder/
RewriteRule (.*)\.html http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Joost it worked! I will still try to implement the same rule for http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/ . Tried a lot but so far only you solution worked. Note that I changed the last line to RewriteRule (.*)\.html http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] and that I added the rule just after RewriteBase /